# Using CURSOR in Oracle 11g database to locate all matches for specifed string in DB

Tags: oracle-11g, cursors

As far as I know in Microsoft SQL Server it is possible to use CURSOR to "scan" database and get all tables/entries where specified string is mentioned. Can I do this in Oracle 11g DB? Any caveats/limits for such scenario?

Comment: Are you looking for cases where a string exists in a column name?  In a table name?  Or in some row somewhere in the table?

Comment: In the table values not in column/table names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hard-pressed to imagine how you'd accomplish that with a single cursor in SQL Server.

The same question has been asked and [answered on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389666/oracle-search-all-tables-all-columns-for-string/6389779#6389779).  If you want to get really tricky, you could also use an [XML Query to search across objects](http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2007/04/how-do-i-store-the-counts-of-all-tables.html) with a single query.

In either case, the result is going to be insanely slow since you're full scanning every table at least if not once per character column.

Comment: I don't care about speed particularly as I have non production copy of database against which I can run this query, the only thing I need is to be sure that I know all locations in database where particular value/string is present - so I'm trying to find the best way to get this information

Comment: @Mikhail - The answer I gave on StackOverflow should work.  It'll be slow as dirt.  But it will work.